# How do I change into kiosk mode with powershell with a specific website

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, microsoft-edge, kiosk-mode

I was looking for a solution to automate the creation of a kiosk mode with a specific website in Microsoft Edge. Because this is easily possible in the UI and there is absolutely no useful documentation about this in pure PowerShell, I reverse-engineered the process. The result is a PowerShell script I put in the **answer section**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to my GitHub repository, where you can find the PowerShell script.
As mentioned there, this currently only works in Windows 10 (I will update it in the future)
https://github.com/ProRedMax/Kiosk-Mode-with-pre-defined-website-Powershell

Comment: Dude your script is nice. How did you work that out? I presumed you did a capture of the Windows Setting GUI? I was going to suggest adding an option for SCCM deployments. Just adding these lines could do it, along with some TS variables, but I am currently testing it now so not sure if it works yet.
`$tsenv = New-Object -COMObject Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment`
`$user = TSEnv(“Kiosk_User”)`
`$userDesc = TSEnv(“Kiosk_Description”)`
`$website = TSEnv(“Kiosk_Website”)`

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in 21H2 version.

Comment: @Rosski Thank you :) . Yea I think I mentioned it in the GitHUB Repo that it is not working for version 21H2 and above. After really long hours I wrote my own UWP App with an inbuild browser to get it working. But I did manage to make a "fake kiosk". This means that it looks like a kiosk but you can get out if you know that it is fake. I will update the repository today with the "fake kiosk" method if you are interested. PS: I did a regshot and wrote a java program to "analyse" the changes and output me Powershell CommandLets

Comment: The fake kiosk only affects 21H2 and above versions

Comment: @Rosski hey, I updated the script with my 21H2 solution. Again, this is only a "fake kiosk" so you can "get out" if you know some windows shortcuts. Regarding your SCCM solution: Feel free to open a pull request on the repository :)

Comment: This is great, thanks so much for taking the time to update it. I have saved your script and will have a play once I get back to tinkering with a Kiosk. <3