Is there any way to prompt the user using powershell script such that the user is not able to ignore it
I am able to give a prompt to the user using powershell script but the issue is that the user is able to ignore it. What I mean is the user is able to open other programs and file even when the prompt is there. I want that when the user is prompted he should not be able to open any other app or file until he reacts to the prompt.
`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
    "Do you want to change the BIOS password?",
    "BIOS Password Change",
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OKCancel,
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Question
)
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Change BIOS Password"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,220)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"


$labelOld = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelOld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$labelOld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$labelOld.Text = "Enter old BIOS password:"
$form.Controls.Add($labelOld)
$textboxOld = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxOld.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textboxOld.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textboxOld)


$labelNew = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelNew.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$labelNew.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$labelNew.Text = "Enter new BIOS password:"
$form.Controls.Add($labelNew)
$textboxNew = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxNew.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,90)
$textboxNew.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textboxNew)

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,130)
$button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$button.Text = "OK"
$button.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.Controls.Add($button)

$form.Add_Shown({
    $textboxOld.Select()
})
$form.AcceptButton = $button

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $oldPassword = $textboxOld.Text
    $newPassword = $textboxNew.Text
    (gwmi -Class Lenovo_SetBiosPassword -Namespace root\wmi).SetBiosPassword("pap,$oldPassword,$newPassword,ascii,us")
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
        "Restart your device to see the changes",
        "Operation Cancelled",
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Exclamation
    )
 
} else {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
        "Password change cancelled.",
        "Operation Cancelled",
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Exclamation
    )
}
} else {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
        "Password change cancelled.",
        "Operation Cancelled",
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Exclamation
    )
}`


This is the powershell script I used to give a prompt to the user to change the bios password.But the user is able to ignore this prompt. He should react to this prompt before accessing any other file.

I think this is more design question (as apposed to a coding question) for the https://superuser.com/ site. The thing is that the (Windows) operating system is designed so that an application by default can't (easy) get exclusief rights over other applications and the operating system itself. Maybe to do something like you describe, is to startup in kiosk-mode first and when your interface is satisfied, restart in normal mode (see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72358787/1701026)

You can set the TopMost property to true on the form to have it sit in front of over non-TopMost applications, but that’s not absolute priority - other “TopMost” apps can sit in front of yours, and Task Manager takes priority over all TopMost applications if it’s configured to be on top. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
